# The most efficient implementation to find latest block in a blockchain

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, blockchain

So I am making a blockchain project, and I've come to the problem where I need to get the latest block.
Now whoever doesn't know how blockchain works, it's basically built like this:

BLOCK 0:

```
Previous hash: 0

Hash: 104973
```

BLOCK 1:

```
Previous hash: 104973

Hash: 859236
```

BLOCK 2:

```
Previous hash: 859236

Hash: 523564
```

So it creates a chain linked by hashes.
Now each block has a file that represents the block, all in 1 folder, so the folder name is "Blocks", and it contains 3 files ("BLOCK104973.bl", "BLOCK859236.bl", "BLOCK523564.bl").

Now I need to get the latest block, what would be the most efficient way to do this?
What I thought of:

Loop over all the blocks (files) in the folder and make a list of their hashes, then loop again on each hash and see which hash does not have a corresponding block (a block that has a previous hash which equals to the current hash in the loop).

But it seems highly inefficient, and was wondering if anyone has any better idea (or if there is a way that people usually use in a blockchain)?
Note that getting the block by the file change date is not reliable enough for me.

Comment: It's just a doubly linked list... You could always keep a reference to the most recent link

Comment: @OneCricketeer Unfortunately I can't keep a reference to the most recent link as it is not reliable enough, for example in the event of a complete blockchain change.

Comment: If the complete thing changes, then you have a new end block, and can discard the old reference... But blockchains should be immutable, so that shouldn't be allowed, anyway

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes you are right, but it’s a different kind of implementation of blockchain and theoretically you can have multiple blockchains at once.

Answer (score 0):

Traversing blockchain starting from genesis block is kinda rare task. Usually blockchain node has the latest block either from network or generating it. So it is much easier to go in opposite direction following *previous block hash* link. And then single linked list can be reversed.

Also most, if not  all, blockchain implementations utilize some database to speedup access to data. Bitcoin core uses LevelDB. One of the indexes has block has as key and the value is block index record that contains block header, block height (block number) and some other info. LevelDB files are kept in *.bitcoin/blocks/index* directory.